# What is /overwrite parameter for when calling "tfs get"

Tags: command-line, parameters, tfs

TFS command line has the `get` command as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx7sdeyf%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

And the option parameter /overwrite which says *"Overwrites writable files that are not checked out."*

I have no idea what that means. Please share if you know what it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Visual Studio 2012 version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx7sdeyf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the same web page is a little more helpful:

> By default, the system does not retrieve an item if it is writable
>   (that is, if its read-only attribute is cleared) on the client
>   machine. This option overrides the default behavior and overwrites a
>   writable item, unless the item is checked out.

For example, let's say you have a .config file in source control. You may want to make some local changes to the file without checking it out, so you just change the file from read only to writable and make your change. If a new version is checked in and you do a get, your local version will not be overwritten with the newer one from source control by default, unless you use `/overwrite`.

Comment: Your example is absolutely clear and clean my issue. Thank you!